# Is this a bug in dotnet Regex-Parser?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I just wrote a regexp to do a basic syntax checking if a string is a valid math formular.
I just define a group of valid chars and check if a string matches (I shortend the regex a little:

```
    private static readonly String validFormuar =  @"^[\d\+-\*\/]+$";
    private static bool IsValidFormular(String value)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(value, validFormuar);
    }
```

I will only allow digits, +, -, * and / in this example.
Because +,* and / are special chars in regular expressions I escaped them.
However this code throws an ArgumentException (translated from german)

```
"^[\d\+-\*\/]+$" is beeing analyzed - [x-y]-area in reversed Order.
```

If I double escape the *

```
    private static readonly String validFormuar =  @"^[\d\+-\\*\/]+$";
```

the result is as expected.
Is this a bug in the System.Text.RegularExpressions parser? Because I consider my first regexp as correct. If not, why do I have to escape the "*" twice?

Comment: If you see hoof prints, think horses—not zebras. The OS is probably not broken. And the database is probably just fine. —Andy Hunt and Dave Thomas :)

Comment: @Firas: that's fine for cowboys but what if you live in the Serengeti.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll find `"-"` is a special character in regexes as well (at least within the `"[]"` bits). It specifies a range of characters, as in `"[0-9]"` meaning and of `"0123456789"`.

The reason your second one works but your first doesn't is because:

- `+` comes after `*` (error in range).
- `+` comes before `\` (no error in range).

To clarify, your second regex `(@"^[\d\+-\\*\/]+$")` actually means:

- `"\d"` ; or
- `"\+" thru "\\"` (quite a large range, including digits and uppercase letters) ; or
- `"*"` ; or
- `"\/"`

Although it compiles, it's not what you want (because of that second bullet point). I'd try this instead:

```
@"^[\d\+\-\*\/]+$"
```

Comment: Obvious mistake was too obvious. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4):

With @"" strings, you don't have to double-escape. In your sample, you also forgot to escape the "-". So the correct one would be:

```
@"^[\d\+\-\*\/]+$"
```

On the other hand, when inside [], you don't need to escape those (only "-"):

```
@"^[\d+\-*/]+$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the - as first char in your expression. Otherwise the parser is looking for a range.